# Number From Database in Python

Tags: python, database, number-formatting

I am a newbie at Python, and wading through the various peculiarities of the language.  One of the peculiarity I found is the output of the following code snippet:

```
qry = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <<TABLE>>'
cursor.execute(qry)
rowCounts = cursor.fetchone()
print("The number of rows in the <<TABLE>> table : {}".format(rowCounts))
```

I am getting the following output on my terminal:

```
Connected to the MySQL database.
The number of rows in the <<TABLE>> table : (150L,)
```

I am stumped by the brackets and the comma.  I have searched for the answer to explain the occurrence, but haven't found any plausible explanation for the format.  Is there something I should be doing differently?

All help is appreciated.

Comment: What database/ORM (i.e. SQLAlchemy)? What's the output of `type(rowCounts)` and `type(rowCounts[0])`? I suspect it's a tuple containing a Long

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output you see is because the rowCounts is a `tuple` containing only 1 element.

a tuple with one item is constructed by following a value with a comma

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I believe I made a boo-boo.  I was trying to use a method to get the information for which I should have been using an attribute.  Now, off I go to learn more about tuple.